# How can I organize my source files in a VS .NET project?

Tags: visual-studio

To create a new class in Visual Studio, I hit Ctrl+Shift+A, then select "Class". The class creation dialog does not give me any option to put the file anywhere. Visual Studio creates the file in the solution root dir.

So now my solution root dir has 20+ files and a mix of .cs, .sln, .csproj etc files.

I want to be able to view my project in a tree structure, where I organize the class files into a folder hierarchy. How can I do this in Visual Studio?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new folders in your solution tree (in mouse right-click menu) and place your new files there (you probably can even drag files from another location). 20+ files is not much of course :)

Comment: I tried this before, but then for some reason all my files ended up being "missing" in my project. I got confused and thought there was some more, complicated way to do it. It was not, not sure what I did before. Anyways, thanks! Oh and 20+ files is only the beginning ;)